# How to avoid ID-conflicts when on-the-fly generating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have this mockup-code:

```
    button.click(function(){generateForm();}

     function generateForm(){
     div.append(<input type='text' id='x'>);
  }
```

I will need the ID in order to access the element individually.

**What is the best way to avoid having ID-conflicts in a scenario like this ?**

Comment: It depends what you're doing with it. It might make most sense to generate ids on the server side.

Comment: I'll update the question with more info regarding the scenario.

Comment: you could add a random number to the id of the input, that way there will be no conflict or maybe check if a given id is already in use before creating a new input with that id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use `class` instead. But if you are still willing to use `id`, you may consider using a counter like this:

```
   var idCounter = 1;
   function generateForm(){
     div.append("<input type='text' id='x-" + (idCounter++) + "'>");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate on how using classes would work in this scenario?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Can you please tell me what you want to do with these text fields?

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need to, you could use the current timestamp for an id.

That obviously produces no duplicate IDs unless you call the function more than once per millisecond *or your users get stuck in timeloops often.*

```
function generateForm(){
    d = new Date();
    div.append('<input type="text" id="unique-id-' + d.getTime() + '" >);
}
```

Edit: Note the `unique-id-` prefix, for id shouldn't be numeric only.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep track of an external counter, try:

```
  function makeAVeryRandomId () {
    var d = new Date(),
        a = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
        i = 10,
        m = '';

    while (i--) {
      m += a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    };

    return d.getTime() + m;
  };
```

Bear in mind that `ID`s shouldn't start with a number, so prefix the random number with a letter (or two).